# transforming XML to XSL issue

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap

I am relativity new to web services / soap / XML and XSLT and am close to grasping the basics of it but could really do with some guidance/help as I am stuck at the moment.

I have a web service which pulls information into a response (using SharePoint workflow)

Response from request-

```
<!-- language: XML -->
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
   <GetHouseholdByRefResponse xmlns="http://schemas.*****.co.uk/*****/****/**">
    <GetHouseholdByRefResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorMessage i:nil="true" />
    <Success>true</Success>
    <Household>
      <UserFieldList />
      <CaseWorkerContactName></CaseWorkerContactName>
      <CaseWorkerContactTelNo></CaseWorkerContactTelNo>
      <CompanyCode>001                 </CompanyCode>
      <ContactKey>00000</ContactKey>
      <CorrespondenceAddress />
      <CorrespondenceDesignation></CorrespondenceDesignation>
      <CorrespondencePostCodeValue i:nil="true" />
      <CorrespondencePreamble></CorrespondencePreamble>
      <Description>Joe Bloggs </Description>
      <DisplayCompanyCodes></DisplayCompanyCodes>
      <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
      <ForwardingAddress />
      <ForwardingDesignation></ForwardingDesignation>
      <ForwardingPostCodeValue i:nil="true" />
      <ForwardingPreamble></ForwardingPreamble>
      <Id>000000000</Id>
      <IsVulnerable>false</IsVulnerable>
      <NextOfKinAddress />
      <NextOfKinDesignation></NextOfKinDesignation>
      <NextOfKinName></NextOfKinName>
      <NextOfKinPhone></NextOfKinPhone>
      <NextOfKinPostCodeValue i:nil="true" />
      <NextOfKinPreamble></NextOfKinPreamble>
      <NumberOfChildren>0</NumberOfChildren>
      <PostCodeValue>AB1 C23  </PostCodeValue>
      <PropertyReference i:nil="true" />
      <Reference>000000000   </Reference>
      <ReferralContactName></ReferralContactName>
      <ReferralContactTelNo></ReferralContactTelNo>
      <Size>1</Size>
    </Household>
  </GetHouseholdByRefResult>
   </GetHouseholdByRefResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see it returns a lot of information, most I don’t need, all I want to do i pick out a certain element say **description** for example

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

                     <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-    8" indent="no"/>

                     <xsl:template match="/">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
                     </xsl:template>

                    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get nothing back, like there is no description. I know there is a description as when I test the following code it transforms the entire result into a string, which suggests that I have got some of the XSL language wrong when trying to specify just one element

```
                     <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-    8" indent="no"/>

                     <xsl:template match="/">
                        <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
                     </xsl:template>

                    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Also, if there are any people out there good on this subject I would be interested to hear if you could recommend any resources where to learn this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there *is* a Description, but (1) it is not a child of the `/` root node, and (2) it and its ancestors have *namespaces* that you need to define and use when addressing them, e.g.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.*****.co.uk/*****/****/**"
exclude-result-prefixes="s x">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="s:Envelope/s:Body/x:GetHouseholdByRefResponse/x:GetHouseholdByRefResult/x:Household/x:Description"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```